# How to find the column name of last non-NA value for per row

Tags: r, dataframe

```
a1=c('USA',9,8,rep(NA,5)) 
a2=c('CHN',NA,NA,3,NA,3,NA,4) 
a3=c('JPN',11,6,7,NA,5,NA,NA) 
M=rbind(a1,a2,a3) 
colnames(M) <- c('country', '2008', '2009', '2010', '2011', '2012', '2013', '2014')
```

Hi, I want to find the length from column 2008 to the last non-na value for each row. The expected result is: 
USA 2
CHN 7
JPN 5

This is where I am now. I found the value of last non-NA value for each row, but what should I next?

```
ind <- !is.na(M) 
tapply(M[ind], row(M)[ind], tail, 1)
```

Comment: Try `max.col(!is.na(M[,-1]), 'last')`

Comment: using `which` is another way. `f <- function(x) rev(which(!is.na(x)))[1]`, then `tapply(M[,-1],row(M[,-1]),f)`

Comment: Thank you both. It works really well!