# Column name of last non-NA row per row; using tidyverse solution?

Tags: r, dplyr, na, tidyverse, tibble

**Brief Dataset description:** I have survey data generated from Qualtrics, which I've imported into R as a tibble. Each column corresponds to a survey question, and I've preserved the original column order (to correspond with the order of the questions in the survey).

**Problem in plain language:** Due to normal participant attrition, not all participants completed all of the questions in the survey. I want to know how far each participant got in the survey, and the last question they each answered before stopping.

**Problem statement in R:** I want to generate (using tidyverse):

- 1) A new column (*lastq*) that lists, for each row (i.e. for each participant), the name of the last non-NA column (i.e. the name of the last question they completed).
- 2) A second new column that lists the number of the column in *lastq*

---

**Sample dataframe df**

```
df <- tibble(
  year = c(2015, 2015, 2016, 2016),
  grade = c(1, NA, 1, NA),
  height = c("short", "tall", NA, NA),
  gender = c(NA, "m", NA, "f")
 )
```

**Original df**

```
  # A tibble: 4 x 4
   year grade height gender
  <dbl> <dbl>  <chr>  <chr>
1  2015     1  short   <NA>
2  2015    NA   tall      m
3  2016     1   <NA>   <NA>
4  2016    NA   <NA>      f
```

**Desired final df**

```
   # A tibble: 4 x 6
   year grade height gender  lastq lastqnum
  <dbl> <dbl>  <chr>  <chr>  <chr>    <dbl>
1  2015     1  short   <NA> height        3
2  2015    NA   tall      m gender        4
3  2016     1   <NA>   <NA>  grade        2
4  2016    NA   <NA>      f gender        4
```

---

There are some other related questions, but I can't seem to find any answers focused on extracting the column names (vs. [the values themselves](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/39934159/get-value-of-last-non-na-row-per-column-in-data-table)) based on a tibble of mixed variable classes (vs. [all numeric](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/49325845/how-to-find-the-column-name-of-last-non-na-value-for-per-row)), using a tidyverse solution

What I've been trying - I know there's something I'm missing here... :

- `ds %>% map(which(!is.na(.)))`
- `ds %>% 
    map(tail(!is.na(.), 2))`
- `ds %>% 
    rowwise() %>% 
    mutate(last = which(!is.na(ds)))`

?

---

Thank you so much for your help!

Comment: `max(which(!is.na(ds)))`?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Write a function that solves the problem, following James' suggestion but a little more robust (handles the case when all answers are NA)

```
f0 = function(df) {
    idx = ifelse(is.na(df), 0L, col(df))
    apply(idx, 1, max)
}
```

The `L` makes the 0 an integer, rather than numeric. For a speed improvement (when there are many rows), use the matrixStats package

```
f1 = function(df) {
    idx = ifelse(is.na(df), 0L, col(df))
    matrixStats::rowMaxs(idx, na.rm=TRUE)
}
```

Follow markus' suggestion to use this in a dplyr context

```
mutate(df, lastqnum = f1(df), lastq = c(NA, names(df))[lastqnum + 1])
df %>% mutate(lastqnum = f1(.), lastq = c(NA, names(.))[lastqnum + 1])
```

or just do it

```
lastqnum = f1(df)
cbind(df, lastq=c(NA, names(df))[lastqnum + 1], lastqnum)
```

**Edited after acceptance** I guess the tidy approach would be first to tidy the data into long form

```
df1 = cbind(gather(df), id = as.vector(row(df)), event = as.vector(col(df)))
```

and then to group and summarize

```
group_by(df1, id) %>%
    summarize(lastq = tail(event[!is.na(value)], 1), lastqname = key[lastq])
```

This doesn't handle the case when here are no answers.

Comment: I'm not sure this follows idomatic tidyverse, given the use of ifelse instead of if_else, cbind instead of bind_cols, etc.